# what's the regular expression that will capture these elements?

Tags: regex

assuming that you have a string with an arbitrary number of lines, each of which follows a pattern such as the one illustrated below,

```
 Line 498:          [Badsds()]
 Line 499:          protected override void Something() {
 Line 500:              base.Something();
```

What's the regular expression that will capture the text after "Line \d+:\s*"?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried this: "Line \d+:\s*\S.*\s*"

Comment: Your regex contains no capturing groups.

Comment: where is the language tag or what language are you using..

Comment: 0_o Where did the "<x>" come from?

Comment: @JohnSmith you are using c# right!

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments.  It is annoying to read at best.  Also, what does "doesn't work" mean?  "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `c#` you can do

```
List<string> lstMatch=Regex.Matches(input,@"(?<=^\s*Line \d+:)(.*)$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Multiline)
                           .Cast<Match>()
                           .Select(x=>x.Value)
                           .ToList();
```

OR

```
List<string> lstMatch=Regex.Matches(input,@"^\s*Line \d+:\s*(.*)$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Multiline)
                               .Cast<Match>()
                               .Select(x=>x.Groups[1].Value)
                               .ToList();
```

If you want to avoid reading all lines at once

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fileLocation))
    {
       Regex.Match(line,@"^\s*Line \d+:\s*(.*)$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
    }
```

Comment: your regex is not working:                foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, "^Line \\d+:\\s*(?<x>(.*))$"))
                {
                    builder.AppendLine(match.Groups["x"].Value);
                }

Comment: @JohnSmith check out the edit if you want to avoid loading in one shot

Answer (score 0):

```
Line \d+:\s*(.*)
```

Captures everything after the pattern you indicated in the first capturing group.